# Run cron jobs programmatically

Tags: magento2, cron

In the Magento 2 CLI, the command to run cron jobs is `cron:run --group="[cron group]"`

However, I was not able to find how this translates into actual PHP code, i.e. where `cron:run` is mapped to.

Is it possible to execute `cron:run` programmatically from within my module? Something like:

```
function run() {
    Cron::execute(CRON_GROUP);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on why you would need to do that? Thanks

Comment: Actually it's for testing purposes--I have a module that executes a number of behaviors in the main Magento 2 module and provides a REST interface to control this. I could imagine some other use cases though, i.e. if someone wanted to run all crons at a certain frequency regardless of the actual frequency defined by the module developer, etc.

Comment: what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: I tried checking what Magento itself run on cron:run, but beyond that I really don't have any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside here

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Cron/Console/Command/CronCommand.php#L116

`$params[self::INPUT_KEY_GROUP] = $input->getOption(self::INPUT_KEY_GROUP);`

`$cronObserver = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Cron::class, ['parameters' => $params]);`

So basically you are passing `$params['group'] = whatever`

And then

$cronObserver->launch();